# Переименовать вершины графа BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bgl

Как задавать имена вершинам в моем коде?

хочу поменять 0-3 на названия например А1, А2
[image]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list<
        vecS,
        vecS,
        undirectedS
> MyGraph;

int main()
{
    MyGraph g(5);

    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(3, 1, g);

    ofstream f("graph.dot");
    write_graphviz(f, g);
    f.close();
    system("C:/Graphwiz/bin/dot.exe graph.dot -Kcirco -Tsvg -o graph.svg");
    system("start graph.svg");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Не уверен, что это возможно. Однако, Вы можете добавить ярлыки для необходимых вершин:</strike> См. update.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct VtxProps { std::string name; };
struct EdgProps { std::string name; };

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VtxProps, EdgProps>;

int main() {
    Graph g(3);
    g[0].name = "A0";
    g[1].name = "A1";
    g[2].name = "A2";

    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(3, 1, g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout, g,
            make_label_writer(get(&VtxProps::name, g)),
            make_label_writer(get(&EdgProps::name, g)));
}
```

[Пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iUjXfUwZZ7a0m2yV) на wandbox.

Upd.: детальнее посмотрел документацию, если я правильно понимаю, это то, что Вам нужно:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

using VertexProperty = boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>;

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperty>;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;

int main() {
    Graph g;    

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        boost::add_vertex(Graph::vertex_property_type("A" + std::to_string(i)), g);
    }

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g));

    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(3, 1, g);

    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}
```

[Пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jMp9wr3qhsqWsfiS) на wandbox.

[image: Результат:]

Comment: Ваш ответ особо не помог, но спасибо.

Comment: @regdayzk, не за что.

Comment: @regdayzk, обновил ответ, проверьте, это ли Вам было нужно.